# List displays its precedent value

Tags: java, spring-boot, modelmapper

So I am using a modelmapper to convert all my entities, worked fine until now.
I have an entity TaskDTO with a List of Double in its attributes.
I can recuperate this list but once a request is made, all next requests get me the same list.

Here is the part for my converter:

```
public static TaskDTO converTaskToDTO(Task source) {
    List<Double> icList = new ArrayList<>();
    for (ChargeInitial c : source.getCharge()) {
        icList.add(c.getCharge());
    }
    System.out.println(icList);
    TypeMap<Task, TaskDTO> typeMap = modelMapper.getTypeMap(Task.class, TaskDTO.class);
    if (typeMap == null) {

        modelMapper.addMappings(new PropertyMap<Task, TaskDTO>() {
            @Override
            protected void configure() {
                map().setLot(source.getLot().getName());
                map().setProject(source.getLot().getProject().getName());
                map().setCollaborator(source.getCollaborator().getEmail());
                map().setCharge(icList);

            }
        });
    }

    return modelMapper.map(source, TaskDTO.class);

}
```

However the sysout prints the right list for me.

For exemple if in the first request I get charge[1,2] for that list, the second request will be also [1,2] for every charge list even though I get the right esult which is [1,2,3,4,5] in my system.out.

What could be the problem?

**EDIT**

I changed the method setCharge in TaskDTO as follows, works fine.

```
public void setCharge(List<ChargeInitial> charge) {
    List<Double> list = new ArrayList<>();
    for (ChargeInitial c : charge) {
        list.add(c.getCharge());
    }
    this.charge=list;
}
```

Comment: Once you add the mappings wouldn't the typemap lookup return not-null?

Comment: no since it is a new request .

Comment: ... And you verified that `typeMap` is null? Does `addMappings` not add to a registry of mappings, which is then referred to by subsequent `getTypeMap` calls?

Comment: typemap is actually null only the fisrt request, second one I get ,TypeMap[Task -> TaskDTO]

Comment: Right, so it won't be calling `setCharge`. Once you have a typemap you only need to do the actual conversion. You've conflated mapper configuration w/ doing the actual mapping.

Comment: how come then that it calls correctly the other setters?

Comment: I don't understand the question; you already confirmed that code isn't running after the first call after app startup. It would exhibit the exact same behavior with the other setters as with `setCharge`/`icList`.

Comment: no what I said that it's only not working for setCharge, I get the right results for all the other setters

Comment: ... `icList` is not retrieved from the source. When you call `map` there is no mapping for that value; it's set once (when `typeMap != null`) from the closure.

Comment: Ok I understand the cause nw, do you have any suggestion to resolve it?

Comment: Change the mapping?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`Converter`](http://modelmapper.org/user-manual/converters/), `List<ChargeInitial>` to `List<Double>`.

```
public static TaskDTO converTaskToDTO(Task source) {

    TypeMap<Task, TaskDTO> typeMap = modelMapper.getTypeMap(Task.class, TaskDTO.class);
    if (typeMap == null) {

        PropertyMap<Task, TaskDTO> mapping = new PropertyMap<Task, TaskDTO>() {
            @Override
            protected void configure() {
                map().setLot(source.getLot().getName());
                map().setProject(source.getLot().getProject().getName());
                map().setCollaborator(source.getCollaborator().getEmail());
            }
        };
        modelMapper.addMappings(mapping);

        Converter<List<ChargeInitial>, List<Double>> chargeInitialConverter = new AbstractConverter<>() {
            @Override
            protected List<Double> convert(List<ChargeInitial> source) {
                List<Double> icList = new ArrayList<>();
                for (ChargeInitial c : source) {
                    icList.add(c.getCharge());
                }
                System.out.println(icList);
                return icList;
            }
        };
        modelMapper.addConverter(chargeInitialConverter);

    }

    return modelMapper.map(source, TaskDTO.class);

}
```